# JQuery plugin to animate overlay

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a JQuery plugin to animate the appearance and disappearance of an overlay div.    Something like what Rackspace has here:

http://www.rackspacecloud.com/

After staring at the page for 30 seconds or so, a div comes sliding down from the top asking you whether you want to chat with a rep.  If you ignore the div for a period of time it slides back up.

I know I could hand code all this using timers and animate() and such, but hoping someone has done it for us already.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to add a comment that might enlighten us in the right direction? +1.

Comment: That's a fairly specific requirement and it would probably be easiest just to code it using jQuery's animation facilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Will is correct.  animate() is more powerful than I had realized.  I was able to get it doing most of what I want with 4 lines of code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $j("#survey").show();
  $j("#survey").animate({top: "300px"}, 2000);
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is very Powerful.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#survey").delay(10000).show().animate({top: "300px"}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI is another great thing to have with lots of animation effects. Few like :

```
$( "#survey" ).toggle( "blind", {},500 );
$( "#survey" ).toggle( "bounce", {},500 );
$( "#survey" ).toggle( "clip", {},500 );
$( "#survey" ).toggle( "drop", {},500 );
```

For more effects , visit https://jqueryui.com/toggle/